# Which /etc/pam.d file for a regular terminal?

Tags: pam, etc, ulimit

I have edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` to set the `ulimit` `rtprio` permanently. If I ssh to localhost or open a shell with `su` it works fine, but if I just log in to Ubuntu (16.04) and open a Gnome Terminal, it does not as confirmed by `ulimit -a`.

I think I need to add `session required pam_limits.so` to one of the files in `/etc/pam.d/`, but which one? I have already tried `/etc/pam.d/unity`, `lightdm`, `login` and `common-session`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file and reboot:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Comment: Already done, it had no effect.

Comment: just adjust the `limits.conf` file. Reboot. And check the value with `ulimit -r`